# Document a config macro with doxygen

Tags: c, macros, doxygen

I want to document a configuration macro with doxygen. That macro is not defined in source code but is required to be defined using compiler definition settings.

Since I have no definition I tried something like the following which I found in the doxygen manual (I added this snippet to the header that is using the macro for conditional compilation):

```
/*! \def MY_CONFIG_MACRO
    \brief Brief

    Details.
*/
```

However that documentation does not appear in the generated HTML files. Any idea why the above doesn't work? How can I document a compiler defined macro in the context where it is used?

Comment: I doubt it's possible like that. I would just mention this requirement in the general documentation of the component that requires it. That could be the documentation of a function, a group or even the main page.

Comment: Hmm, from the doc I would agree this is the correct way. Did you try a [mcve]? Maybe you have something wrong in your doxygen-config?

Comment: @Olaf: I tried the above snippet in an empty header file with a fresh doxywizard config file. Doxygen says "warning: documentation for unknown define MY_CONFIG_MACRO found". HTML is empty. If I define the macro the documentation appears.

Comment: You should have such information in your question! Ok, how about a conditional definition of that macro? You should guard it exists anyway.

Comment: A misunderstanding... *after you asked me*, I tried it in an empty header file :-) Yes that would be a solution. If I can't get the above work it could also be a solution to create an entire header file that exists in doxygen only. I will think about that.

Comment: Perhaps you could document the macro in the `\mainpage` section, or some other `\section`, or even in a separate Markdown format file mentioned by the `INPUT` tag in the Doxygen configuration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the very same problem, it was resolved like this:

In the doxygen configuration file, add:

```
PREDEFINED = IN_DOXYGEN
```

Somewhere in the source code, add:

```
/*
  Exporting cmake compilation flags to doxygen,
  so they get documented.
*/
#ifdef IN_DOXYGEN
#define MY_CONFIG_MACRO
#endif /* IN_DOXYGEN */
```

Then the documentation for MY_CONFIG_MACRO is picked up properly.

Comment: I think that's a good solution. Still for my case I decided to create a separate header file that is only processed by doxygen and not included in the code project.