# Documenting conditional exclusive code in Doxygen

Tags: c-preprocessor, doxygen

Consider

```
// EXTERNAL_MACRO is an external macro defined to some value by build system

#if EXTERNAL_MACRO == 1
#   define EXCLUSIVE_MACRO_ONE
#elif EXTERNAL_MACRO == 2
#   define EXCLUSIVE_MACRO_TWO
#else
#   define EXCLUSIVE_MACRO_OTHER
#endif
```

At built time, only one of the EXCLUSIVE_MACRO_... macros is defined.

*How can one document **all** three EXCLUSIVE_MACRO_... macros in Doxygen?*

`PREDEFINED` configuration setting is not helpful for this because it allows to define EXTERNAL_MACRO to only a single value (and therefore document only a single EXCLUSIVE_MACRO_...).

This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41412390/2325279) offers a work-around solution that does the job but it requires an additional logic. I am looking for a simpler answer, one that uses Doxygen configuration (if possible) rather than modifying the original code (though some modification is of course fine).

Answer (score 1):

See related question and answer:
[Document a config macro with doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328395/document-a-config-macro-with-doxygen/39342804#39342804)

Basically:

In the doxygen configuration file, add:

```
PREDEFINED = IN_DOXYGEN
```

Somewhere in the source code, add:

```
/*
  Exporting build configuration macros to doxygen,
  so they get documented.
*/
#ifdef IN_DOXYGEN
#   define EXCLUSIVE_MACRO_ONE
#   define EXCLUSIVE_MACRO_TWO
#   define EXCLUSIVE_MACRO_THREE
#endif /* IN_DOXYGEN */
```

Then the documentation for these macros is picked up properly.

If you don't want to change the source, you can add `EXCLUSIVE_MACRO_ONE` and friends in `PREDEFINED`, instead of setting `EXTERNAL_MACRO`.

Comment: I like your last suggestion most: add a list of macros to `PREDEFINED` setting.  However, it does not work for me.  I am using Doxygen v1.8.14.  Perhaps another setting is required?  It is as if Doxygen generates macro documentation when it encounters `#define MACRO ...` in source code and as if it uses the `PREDEFINED` setting only to evaluate preprocessor expressions.

Comment: @Petr, you probably need to check other doxygen settings related to the pre processor, like ENABLE_PREPROCESSING (= YES), MACRO_EXPANSION (=YES), EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF (=YES), and EXPAND_AS_DEFINED (add your macros here). Personally, I prefer to modify the source instead, it is easier to maintain. You can also create a new header file, used by doxygen only, if changing an existing source file is an issue.

Comment: Before more experimentation with the settings I realized there is a small problem with the approach anyhow.  Your answer inspired what I think is a good solution for me.  Too long for a comment so I will format it as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54075299/2325279).

**PROBLEM**: We have an existing header that, based on an external macro (provided by build system), defines one of several exclusive macros during compilation. Since only one of the compile-time macros is defined (for each individual build), it is difficult to add Doxygen documentation to all of the exclusive options.

```
// DEFINED_EXTERNALLY is a macro provided by the build system (e.g. via -D). It is defined as 1, 2, or some other natural number.

// Based on DEFINED_EXTERNALLY we want to define one of several exclusive DEFINED_HERE_... macros (e.g. DEFINED_HERE_1, DEFINED_HERE_2, and DEFINED_HERE_OTHER).

// First, we check that none of the DEFINED_HERE_... macros is defined yet.
#if defined(DEFINED_HERE_1) || defined(DEFINED_HERE_2) || defined(DEFINED_HERE_OTHER)
#   error "Conflict: macro DEFINED_HERE_... is already defined!"
#endif

// Then, we define one, and only one, of the DEFINED_HERE_... macros.
#if DEFINED_EXTERNALLY == 1
#   define DEFINED_HERE_1
#elif DEFINED_EXTERNALLY == 2
#   define DEFINED_HERE_2
#else
#   define DEFINED_HERE_OTHER
#endif
```

**SOLUTION**: We temporarily define all variants of the DEFINED_HERE_... macros, together with their documentation.  This will cause Doxygen to generate documentation for all of them.  We then undefine all of the variants and resume normal macro definition logic. 
 As a result, we will have documentation for all variants yet only one of them will be defined during compilation  as was the case before adding the documentation.

Original code

```
// DEFINED_EXTERNALLY is a macro provided by the build system (e.g. via -D). It is defined as 1, 2, or some other natural number.

// Based on DEFINED_EXTERNALLY we want to define one of several DEFINED_HERE_... macros (e.g. DEFINED_HERE_1, DEFINED_HERE_2, and DEFINED_HERE_OTHER).

// First, we check that none of the DEFINED_HERE_... macros is defined yet.
#if defined(DEFINED_HERE_1) || defined(DEFINED_HERE_2) || defined(DEFINED_HERE_OTHER)
#   error "Conflict: macro DEFINED_HERE_... is already defined!"
#endif
```

**New inserted code to generate documentation**

```
/// \brief Value 1.
/// \details It does the following...
#define DEFINED_HERE_1
#undef DEFINED_HERE_1
/// \brief Value 2.
/// \details It does the following...
#define DEFINED_HERE_2
#undef DEFINED_HERE_2
/// \brief Other value.
/// \details It does the following...
#define DEFINED_HERE_OTHER
#undef DEFINED_HERE_OTHER
```

Original code

```
// Then, we define one, and only one, of the DEFINED_HERE_... macros.
#if DEFINED_EXTERNALLY == 1
#   define DEFINED_HERE_1
#elif DEFINED_EXTERNALLY == 2
#   define DEFINED_HERE_2
#else
#   define DEFINED_HERE_OTHER
#endif
```

NB no change to the default Doxygen settings is required

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
PREDEFINED             =
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      =
```

Comment: This solution is a good workaround for macros but not for conditionally built functions or variables since they can't be undefined I think. Or am I wrong?